# GWT - align composite to right side

Tags: gwt, alignment

In GWT I need a composite similar to Eclipse View

- view composite contains other composites which are placed vertically.
- first row is a View toolbar with multiple PushButton. User clicks them to execute some action. 
  Toolbar has to be aligned to right side of the view composite.
- composites placed in second and subsequent rows are used to
  display some values. These are to be aligned to left side of the view
  composite.

  - [image: View]

With following code snippet i am able to align the toolbar to right and place rest of composites on left

```
CaptionPanel view = new CaptionPanel("Eclipse like view");
VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
view.setContentWidget(vPanel);

ViewToolbar toolbar = new ViewToolbar();   // custom composite
vPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
vPanel.add(toolbar);        

ViewContent viewContent = new ViewContent(); // custom composite
vPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
vPanel.add(viewContent);
```

This works as required. But I don't know whether tweaking horizontal alignment like this is a good idea.

Is there any better way to align some composites to the right side and others to left side of the panel.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, using things like `HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT` is a good way if it has to be never changed.

another way to do it could be using CSS declaration and methods like `myThing.addStyleName( myCustomStyle )`

or using uibinder's way with style declarations

Comment: Additionally, I would recommend to use a simple FlowPanel instead of the (HTML table based) VerticalPanel, because you don't need the `setHorizontalAlignment()` method anymore.